# Check if record already exists with Javascript in visualforce

Tags: javascript, salesforce, visualforce, soql

```
<apex:page id="Page" standardController="Account" extensions="vidsav" sidebar="false">
    <script src="/soap/ajax/20.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        function dup() {
            alert("test");
            sforce.connection.sessionId = "{!$Api.Session_ID}";
            var res = document.getElementById("Page:form:PB:sd:PBS:Name").value;
            alert(res);
            var qr = sforce.connection.query("select id, Name From Account WHERE name = '" + res + "'");


            alert(qr);

            if (qr.size != 0) {

                if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
                    alert('testdup');
                }

                return false;
            }
        }
    </script>

    <apex:form id="form">
        <apex:pageBlock id="PB" >
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!sc}" var="que" id="sd">
        <apex:column value="{!que.id}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!que.Name}" id="PBS"/>
        <apex:column value="{!que.Industry}"/>
        <apex:column >

        <apex:commandLink action="{!deleteStudent}" onclick="if(!confirm('Are you sure?')) return false;" value="Del">
            <apex:param value="{!que.Id}" name="idToDel" assignTo="{!SelectedStudentId}"/>
         </apex:commandLink>            

         <apex:commandButton value="AddProcess" onclick="dup()" rerender="all"/ ></apex:column>
         </apex:pageBlockTable>
     </apex:pageBlock>

     <apex:inputText value="{!searchstring}" label="Input"/> 
     <apex:commandButton value="Search records" action="{!search}"/> 
     <apex:commandButton value="Clear records" action="{!clear}"/> 

    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**how to get apex column value in javascript? This always return nothing in res
 var res = document.getElementById("Page:form:PB:PBS:Name").value;
          alert(res);**

How pass action function parameter form javascript to call apex method

We have changed for pageblocktable also we defined id after that also not getting value
 
                  
   
  var res = document.getElementById("Page:form:PB:sd:PBS:Name").value;

Comment: Are u sure that you Id is correct? Have u inspect the code in your browser? The last part withe :Name looks a bit strange

Comment: maybe this can help you https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/70094/checking-a-list-if-a-certain-string-exist-in-visualforce-page

Answer (score 0):

**How to get apex column value in javascript?**

You can get it easily by using jQuery. Syntax is

```
$('[id$=PBS]').val()
```

**How pass action function parameter form javascript to call apex method?**

You can pass action function parameter from javascript.

```
<apex:actionFunction action="{!apexMethodName}" name="jsMethodName">
    <apex:param name="firstParam" assignTo="{!apexPropertyName}" value="" />
</apex:actionFunction>
```

So in javascript, you just call the method

```
jsMethodName(param)
```

this `param` will automatically set to your apex controller variable `apexPropertyName`